# Add Item to an existing Java Swing jList (added to a JFrame using Netbeans UI)

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I am using for first time jList elements in my UI.
All UI is being designed using Netbeans UI builder.

I am under Java 8 in case it is relevant.

I am trying to add elements to list.

**This is a screenshot of the JFrame in action:**

[image]

**This is the desired action:**

After pressing `jButton1` the contents of `jTextfield1` will be added as additional item, to `jList1`.

**This is the excerpt of the button action, including the both things I have tried unsucessfully:**

```java
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    String textToAddToList = this.jTextField1.getText();

    //this.jList1.add(textToAddToList);   <<-- this does not work as add method requires a second paramenter Component which I do not understand.

    //this.jList1.setListData(String [])   <<-- I have used this with a different list because I have the whole list at once, but I do not know how to add a single item with this method either. 
}
```

**This is my full replicable code:**

```java
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author me
 */
public class JFrame1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form JFrame1
     */
    public JFrame1() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jList1 = new javax.swing.JList<>();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jList1.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {
            String[] strings = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
            public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
            public String getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jList1);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 313, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton1)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        String textToAddToList = this.jTextField1.getText();

        //this.jList1.add(textToAddToList);
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JFrame1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JFrame1().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> jList1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#mutable. You won't be able to add an element to your JList since its model is not mutable. I strongly advise not to use wysiwyg tools to create your UI, at least not until you're able to write all the code by yourself (which will force you to read the tutorials and the documentation, and understand the fundamental swing concepts like models and components)

Comment: While I think I understand that, I would like to understand how to do this following the normal flow of adding a component using Netbeans UI builder, which does not define (or I do not know where to define it at least) a DefaultListModel, isn't it possibel to retrieve it somehow?

Comment: I can't help with that. I don't use NetBeans, and even if I did, I would use the text editor to write code.

Comment: Is building a modern layout UI in Java Swing by not using a builder the recommended way to go?

Comment: It's been a long time I haven't written a rich client app in Java, but AFAIK, "modern UI" and "swing" are already quite contradictory. JavaFX is the new thing, AFAIK. But anyway, it wouldn't be the recommended way by me. Others of course might have a different opinion.

Comment: I agree that modern and Swing does not match, I did not use the right term. Substitute modern by complex. I have been trying to manually layout components for a long time and it has been when I started to use the Netbeans UI builder when I was actually able to do complex layouts. Doing complex layouts by hand it is actually pretty difficult as some layouts were simply not designed to do that, not only in Swing but in any other toolkit layout technology. Regarding JavaFX I do not need it and it is heavier than Swing. As far as I know Java Swing is not deprecated.

Comment: GroupLayout has specifically been designed to be used by GUI designers, and not by human developers. But there are other layout managers which have been designed to be used by human developers.

Comment: With your inputs and other answer which was deleted (it actually was helpful) I managed to add a DefaultListModel manually at the class constructor and then add the element to the model. Now it works.   `private DefaultListModel jList1Model;
     ... 
    
    jList1Model = new DefaultListModel();
    jList1.setModel(jList1Model);
     ... 
    
    jList1.addElement(textToAddToList);`

Answer (score 0):

This works:

Define a model in your class:

```java
private DefaultListModel jList1Model;
```

Assign the model to the jList item in the constructor:

```java
jList1Model = new DefaultListModel();
jList1.setModel(jList1Model);
```

Add item to the model and not to the jList in the action method (or wherever you want to add an item):

```java
jList1.addElement(textToAddToList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must consistently use DefaultListModel.

```
DefaultListModel listmodel = new DefaultListModel();
JList list = new JList(listmodel);
```

You can not initialise the model with array of string like this:

```
String items[] = String[]{"item 1", "item 2", "item 3"};
listmode.addAll(items);//error
```

But you must initialise with a collection like this:

```
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("item 1", "item 2", "item 3"));
```

Then in actionPerformed(....) you can add this:

```
DefaultListModel defModel = (DefaultListModel)jList1.getModel();
defModel.addElement("new Element");
```